# Press CTRL+W in a vimterminal programatically from vimscript?

Tags: vimscript, terminal-buffer

Say my cursor is in a Vim terminal.

Normally I press <kbd>Ctrl w</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl w</kbd> to flip to from the Vim terminal to my buffer.

How do I do that with vimscript?

I tried the whole `CTRL+SHIFT+V` thing when writing the vimscript and it only gives me a `W` when I press `CTRL+W` afterwards; I was expecting `^w`.

Comment: `CTRL+SHIFT+V` giving you a `W` is quite surprising.

Comment: @romainl Sorry bad wording; it's been fixed.

Comment: Why `CTRL+SHIFT+V`? It's `CTRL+V`.

Comment: @romainl The `SHIFT` makes the `V` uppercase and gives you the green carrot.

Comment: It doesn't have to be uppercase. Control characters make no difference between uppercase and lowercase.

Comment: @romainl I'm on Windows with `gvim.exe` it seems to make a difference here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
call feedkeys("\<C-w>w", "n")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
wincmd w
```

The `:wincmd` command is quite useful in Vim script, and as far as I know it's faster than using `feedkeys()`.